# PHP login scripts prompts failure upon running

Tags: php

I am trying to create a MySQLi login script with PHP that would connect to my SQL database and would authenticate the user with a session variable upon giving a username/email and password. I am using the following script but it prompts failure on every try.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Logging you in... | Project Club</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
                session_start();
            }
            $servername = "censored";
            $serverusername = "censored";
            $serverpassword = "censored";
            $serverdbname = "censored";
            $usernamemail = $_POST["usernamemail"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $serverusername, $serverpassword, $serverdbname);
            if (isset($_POST["username"]) and isset($_POST["password"])) {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$usernamemail' OR email='$usernamemail';";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $hashpwdcheck = password_verify($password, $row["password"]);
                    echo $hashpwdcheck;
                    if ($hashpwdcheck == true) {
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $row["username"];
                        echo "<p>You are successfully logged in.</p>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<p>Invalid login credentials.</p>";
                    }
                }
                mysqli_close($conn);
            } else {
                echo "<p>Invalid login credentials.</p>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you considered that your login details could be wrong?

Comment: have you considered some code indentation?

Comment: I am 100% sure they are correct.

Comment: `session_start()` needs to be on top of script.

Comment: Think there must be one less `<br>`

Comment: you don't need to use a comparison operator for if a variable is true. `if ($hashpwdcheck) {` should be enough

Comment: Still same results.

Comment: @Alex2php rofl good one

Comment: @dgig password_verify() is a core php function

Comment: there's a tiny syntax error at the end, `};`

Comment: @smith ah really? okay thanks

Comment: can you show how you safe the credentials?

Comment: You have one check that is checking `if(!empty($_POST['username'] ...)`. And you have two separate `Invalid...` messages, which one are you seeing, first or second? Because that can help a lot in knowing what the issue might be and I assume it is the second message because `$_POST['username']` is supposed to say `usernamemail`.

Comment: debbing101, echo all variables, make sure they are what they should be. make sure full error checking and display are on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Try changing this

```
if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
```

to this

```
if (!empty($_POST['usernamemail']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
```

Comment: It's different than the original @smith

Comment: where is the difference to original code? (except the extra error-log for "could not pull db row")

Comment: It's different than the original @Jeff

Comment: if it's different, then you could state _where_ and _what_ is different, and most importantly _why_!

Comment: code dump answers with out explanation are basicly useless